# UPDATE Query issue

Tags: sqlite

I am porting my code that used MS Access to Sqlite. 
I am getting problem for UPDATE query,

```
UPDATE Table1 T1, Table2 T2
SET T1.USE_MHE = T2.USE_MHE
WHERE T1.EQ_NAME= T2.EQ_NAME
```

Above query works fine for MS access ADO connection. But for SQLite it's looks like using table shortcut is not possible (Table1 T1) I have 100's of such query to update.
 Please let me know how table shortcut can be used in SQLite update query.

```
5:SqliteError 
near "T1" Syntax error
```

Comment: Why do you have both `Table1` and `Table2` in line one of your `update` statement?  You're just updating `Table1`, right?

Comment: @Jack: San wants to update `Table1` based on values in `Table2`; some databases use that syntax, some require a `FROM` clause in the `UPDATE`, and some don't allow it at all.

Answer (score 0):

The [UPDATE docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) suggest it simply isn't possible.
Maybe you'd be able to hack something up with virtual or temporary tables, but I think it's going to be way more complicated than just using the full table names.

Aside of that, you could simply use whatever alias, and your editor's replace tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1 
set use_mhe=( select use_mhe 
              from table2 
              where eq_name=table1.eq_name )
where use_mhe= ( select use_mhe 
        from table2 
        where eq_name=table1.eq_name )
```

is not null;

Comment: yes this is one option but I am having 100's of such query. And some of those are very complicated than this. So I am looking of alternative to use table shortcuts here.

Comment: SQLite does not support table shortcuts. See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET USE_MHE = (SELECT USE_MHE FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.EQ_NAME = Table2.EQ_NAME)
```